# How change wxLogMessage color and font style?

Tags: c++, logging, console, window, wxwidgets

How to change the font and color of the text inside the window. I want to use fixed-width fonts like "Courier New". And in some texts, change the color of the text.

```
wxLogWindow* w = new wxLogWindow(NULL, wxT("log winnnn"), TRUE, FALSE);

wxLog::SetActiveTarget(w);
wxLogMessage("Logging wxScroll...");
//w->Flush();
w->GetFrame()->Move(20, 20);
```

Comment: I can add a text to window with this command: wxLogMessage("It works %d", 12);

Comment: why not use this: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/latest/classwx_log_text_ctrl.html?

Comment: what you are doing is just a frame. Its not really a text control....

Answer (score 0):

Standard `wxLogWindow` is a pretty simple class which doesn't support what you want. However it's easy to provide your own log target class similar to it which does. I recommend looking at `wxLogWindow` implementation and then adapting it to your needs.

Setting the font is, of course, trivial, as you can just call `SetFont()` on the text control used for logging. And by overriding `DoLogTextAtLevel()` virtual function you can use different colours for text at different levels or, if you prefer, even depending on the contents of the message.